# JavaScript object setting values to object but not updating to firebase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, firebase

There is a node named reader ranks having 14 ranks, when i am trying to calculate points with static code it works fine for me here is some code for that

```
rank_r = getReaderRank(parseFloat(oldPointsOfReder)); 
  userDataReaderRef.update(rank_r); 

function getReaderRank(points) {
  let obj = {};
  if (points >= 0 && points <= 50) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Bronze';
    obj.userRank = 'rank1';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 25;
    obj.userRankPrice = 0.49;
  } else if (points >= 51 && points <= 100) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Silver';
    obj.userRank = 'rank2';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 30;
    obj.userRankPrice = 0.99;
  } else if (points >= 101 && points <= 200) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Gold';
    obj.userRank = 'rank3';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 35;
    obj.userRankPrice = 1.49;
  } else if (points >= 201 && points <= 400) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Platinum';
    obj.userRank = 'rank4';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 40;
    obj.userRankPrice = 1.99;
  } else if (points >= 401 && points <= 800) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Diamond';
    obj.userRank = 'rank5';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 45;
    obj.userRankPrice = 2.49;
  } else if (points >= 801 && points <= 1600) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Master';
    obj.userRank = 'rank6';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 50;
    obj.userRankPrice = 2.99;
  } else if (points >= 1601 && points <= 3200) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Challenger';
    obj.userRank = 'rank7';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 55;
    obj.userRankPrice = 3.49;
  } else if (points >= 3201 && points <= 6400) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Herald';
    obj.userRank = 'rank8';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 60;
    obj.userRankPrice = 3.99;
  } else if (points >= 6401 && points <= 12800) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Guardian';
    obj.userRank = 'rank9';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 65;
    obj.userRankPrice = 4.49;
  } else if (points >= 12801 && points <= 25600) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Crusader';
    obj.userRank = 'rank10';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 70;
    obj.userRankPrice = 4.99;

  } else if (points >= 256001 && points <= 51200) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Archon';
    obj.userRank = 'rank11';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 75;
    obj.userRankPrice = 5.49;
  } else if (points >= 512001 && points <= 100000) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Legend';
    obj.userRank = 'rank12';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 80;
    obj.userRankPrice = 5.99;
  } else if (points >= 100001 && points <= 150000) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Ancient';
    obj.userRank = 'rank13';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 85;
    obj.userRankPrice = 7.99;
  } else if (points >= 150001 && points <= 10000000000) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Archon';
    obj.userRank = 'rank14';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 90;
    obj.userRankPrice = 9.99;
  } else if (points >= 10000000000) {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Archon';
    obj.userRank = 'rank14';
    obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
    obj.commission = 90;
    obj.userRankPrice = 9.99;
  } else {
    obj.userRankBadge = 'Bronze';
    obj.userRank = 'rank1';
    obj.userPoints = '0';
    obj.commission = 25;
    obj.userRankPrice = 0.49;
  }

  return obj;
}
```

But when i am trying to make it dynamic to get all points value from firebase database, following function is setting all values to object but object is not updating values to database

2. Dynamic Method

   function getReaderRank(points) {
     let obj = {};
     let rank = firebase.database().ref("ReaderRanks/").once("value", function(snaps) {
       snaps.forEach(function(child) {
         let item = child.val();
         let i;
         for (i = 0; i <= item; i++) {
           let strtVal = item.startValue;
           let endVal = item.endValue;

   ```
       if (points >= strtVal && points <= endVal) {
         obj.userRankBadge = item.name;
         obj.userRank = item.rank_no;
         obj.userPoints = points.toFixed(2);
         obj.commission = item.commission;
         obj.userRankPrice = item.price;
       }
     }

   });
   ```

   });
     return obj;
   }

Answer (score 2):

> But object is not updating values to database

With the code from your question you are only **reading data *from* the database** (with the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=1#once) method).

If you want to update the values *in* the database, you would need to use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=1#update) or [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=1#set) methods, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: Thank you, these are two ines of code which are being called in above functiona.let rank_r = getReaderRank(parseFloat(oldPointsOfReder));
userDataReaderRef.update(rank_r);

Comment: Sorry but those lines are not in the code of yoru question if I am not mistaking. Please update your question with as much detail as possible. You may have a look at how to ask a question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask